# Is it possible to configure an Android install to have a quick boot time? (<5 seconds)

Tags: android, performance

I am looking at Android for a project (in car entertainment*) in which power consumption, especially when not in use, is a great concern, but the environment is tightly controlled and *predictable*.

The problem however is that Android has no hibernate mode, and is pretty liberal with allowing Apps processor cycles in standby making it hard to gauge power consumption when the device  is not in use and so I would like to shut it down entirely when not needed, which means it needs to boot ***fast***.

I know many Linux variants have achieved [very quick boot times](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/linux-distro-with-the-fastest-boot-598972/page2.html) and less than 10 seconds on some could be considered standard. I have also [read about Androids long boot times](http://elinux.org/Improving_Android_Boot_Time) and it seems a lot of the delays in loading, like on any OS, could be considered optional?

For example, the presentation states that

> "Android can boot without preloading any  classes"

and that this

> "can result in bad application  load times and memory usage later"

But this is not a concern as long as it is deterministic - if you can find which classes an MP3 player required for example, and turned off all the others and gained 10 seconds it doesn't matter that other apps would take 20 seconds to load because it will never load them.

The same thing goes for the network stack which wouldn't be needed, and for many of the packages, certificate checking, etc.

I know 50 seconds to 5 seconds is a **very** tall order, but is there any reason it is not doable?
Has anyone attempted something like it before? Is Android customizable enough to allow this?

**If Android were to be "streamlined" enough, could it boot in 5 seconds?**

EDIT: The hardware this would be targetting would be 'embedded PC level': think http://store.tinygreenpc.com/tiny-green-pcs/trim-slice/h-diskless.html

EDIT: I am also aware of [Ubiquitous QuickBoot](http://www.ubiquitous.co.jp/En/products/middleware/quickboot/) which though highly impressive is most definitely out of my price range!

(*I like Android over 'standard' Linux distros for this because the entire UI design and ecosystem has been geared around simplicity and portability which makes it perfect for this.)

Comment: Although this is not an answer, if you're compiling Android from source you do have the option to force the CPU into deep sleep regardless of which application has requested a wake lock. Android devices can run for days in deep sleep and even check up with the cell tower every few minutes on their 1000-2000 mAh batteries when in this type of CPU power mode.